# TypeError: not enough arguments for format string - Python SQL connection while using %Y-%m

Tags: python, mysql, compiler-errors, python-3.5

```
with engine.connect() as con:

    rs = con.execute("""
                        SELECT  datediff(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(year,'-',month,'-',day), '%Y-%m-%d') , current_date()) 
                        from TABLE 
                        WHERE datediff(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(year,'-',month,'-',day), '%Y-%m-%d') , current_date()) < 900
                        group by STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(year,'-',month,'-',day), '%Y-%m-%d');
                    """)
```

I feel the compiler is getting confused with '%Y-%m-%d', I might be wrong. Could someone help me on how to avoid this error:

> Type Error:not enough arguments for format string

Comment: What are you using to connect to the mysql database? Which package?  You might explain what you are trying to accomplish with your query.

Comment: using sqlalchemy and using MySQL Workbench

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It sees your `%` signs and thinks you want to format the string.  I believe you should be able to replace them with `%%` to indicate that you want the character, not a format substitution.

Comment: Awesome answer.

Answer (score 4):

You need to escape the `%`:

```
with engine.connect() as con:

    rs = con.execute("""
                        SELECT  datediff(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(year,'-',month,'-',day), '%%Y-%%m-%%d') , current_date()) 
                        from TABLE 
                        WHERE datediff(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(year,'-',month,'-',day), '%%Y-%%m-%%d') , current_date()) < 900
                        group by STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(year,'-',month,'-',day), '%%Y-%%m-%%d');
                    """)
```

`%` is a reserved character in MySQL (wildcard).